# Term For The Subject Of An Acquisition

Tags: etymology

If an Acquisitor performs an Acquisition, is their subject referred to as an Acquisitee?

Please give the reasoning for your answer.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing acquired is also called the *acquisition*.

> **acquisition** *noun*
>   1 An asset or object bought or obtained, typically by a library or museum.
>   ‘the legacy will be used for new acquisitions’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/acquisition)